# How can I export correspondent statistics from linear regression model to a table in R?

Tags: r, statistics, export, regression

I am fitting a multiple linear regression model with 1 dependent variable and 45 independent variables. I would like to put the correspondent effect, 95% CI and p-value to table.

My data set is as below:

```
a  b  x1 x2 x3 x4 .... x45
23 15 1 34 4  45       8
10 45 2 15 2  55       18
```

Is there any more convenient way to write the regression syntax rather than writing `lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4`...`+x45, data=df)` as I have 45 variables with different names?

I've tried

```
mod1 <- lm(a ~ x1 + x2 + ....+x45, data=df)
mod2 <- lm(b ~ x1 + x2 + .... +x45, data=df)
```

But I don't know how to put the outcomes into table as following:

```
model variable     effect       95%CI      p
 mod1    x1       177.93  79.16- 276.71   0.003
 mod1    x2       -75.13 -116.46 - -33.8  0.003 
 ...
 mod1    x45      118.61  53.09-184.13    0.005
 mod2    x1       79.53   36.94 - 122.13  0.004
 mod2    x2       201.93  60.48 - 343.38  0.01 
 ...
 mod2    x45      61.56   20.87 - 102.25   0.005
```

It would be great if anyone can help. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your dataset contains only the dependent variable and the relevant predictors, you can specify the regression like this:

```
lm(a ~ ., data = df)
```

In your case you could use `dplyr::select` to remove `b` or `a`:

```
library(dplyr
mod1 <- df %>%
  select(-b) %>%
  lm(a ~ ., data = .)
```

To summarise outcomes in a table, look at the R packages [stargazer](https://www.jakeruss.com/cheatsheets/stargazer/) or [sjPlot](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/articles/tab_model_estimates.html) or [broom](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html). I like `sjPlot::tab_model` as it generates clean HTML tables in RStudio or in RMarkdown documents.

```
library(sjPlot)
iris %>%
  lm(Petal.Length ~ ., data = .) %>%
  tab_model()
```

[image]

Or using `broom::tidy`:

```
library(broom)
iris %>% 
  lm(Petal.Length ~ ., data = .) %>% 
  tidy()

  term              estimate std.error statistic  p.value
  <chr>                <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 (Intercept)         -1.11     0.270      -4.12 6.45e- 5
2 Sepal.Length         0.608    0.0502     12.1  1.07e-23
3 Sepal.Width         -0.181    0.0804     -2.25 2.62e- 2
4 Petal.Width          0.602    0.121       4.96 1.97e- 6
5 Speciesversicolor    1.46     0.173       8.44 3.14e-14
6 Speciesvirginica     1.97     0.245       8.06 2.60e-13
```

Answer (score 0):

When I used lmer function for the regression, this code can extract the table of the results. Please refer the code!

```
RESULT_model1 <- summary(model1<-lmer(LOGTHSMON_SELNG_AMT~ .-BLK_CD-LOGPERTHSMON_SELNG_AMT
                                      - STDR_YM_CD - bub_dong-M201507-M201508-M201509
                                      -STOR_CO
                                      +(1|BLK_CD)
                                      ,data=dta_fin_WEST))


RESULT_model1_cof <- as.data.frame(tidy(RESULT_model1$coefficients))
RESULT_model1_cof$p.value <- 2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(RESULT_model1_cof$t.value)))
RESULT_model1_cof$VAR <- RESULT_model1_cof$.rownames
RESULT_model1_cof$STDERR <- RESULT_model1_cof$Std..Error
```